# How to get the "element name" for selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have (found) a python script whose purpose is to click a certain button on a certain web page. This is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = "https://url"
driver.get(url)
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("name-of-the-button")
button.click()
```

As I understand, "class name" is the name of the button.
My question is how do I know the class name of the specific button on that specific website? What's the proper way to get this information from?

Comment: View the page in a browser. If you're using Chrome, right-click the element you're interested in, and select "inspect" from the drop-down. This will open the Chrome developer tools, with a view of the DOM structure. Most modern browsers support similar features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called the developer tools. If you're using Chrome, [here's](https://nira.com/chrome-developer-tools/#:%7E:text=From%20the%20Chrome%20menu%3A,web%20page%20you%27re%20on.) a good tutorial. Most browsers have a very similar layout.

Essentialy you want to hit F12 to open up the developer tools, hit CTRL+SHIFT+C and click the button you want. On the right, the button source code should be highlighted, and you should be able to see a `class=` attribute.